# how can I use more then 2 output channels in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, soundchannel

I have a usb 8 channel sound card. How can I use these 8 channels from flash to do something like the speaker stereo on channel 1+2, and some athmos on the other channels.

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use these 8 channels from flash to do something like the
>   speaker stereo on channel 1+2, and some atmospherics on the other channels.

AAC codec supports 8-channel audio ( 7.1 surround). 
You could load various AAC sounds (where each file's audio content is mapped to a specific channel during creation of that AAC file).

For example : Your `stereo.aac` could have  only *Front Left* + *Front Right* defined... and your `atmos1.aac` uses *Back Left*, but file `atmos2.aac` uses *Back Right* and so on... (AAC can be contained within some audio-only MP4 or FLV file).

Try the playback test below. If it sounds like what you want to achieve then go ahead and use AAC.

(audio source : https://www2.iis.fraunhofer.de/AAC/multichannel.html)

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
ns.client = new Object();

ns.play("https://www2.iis.fraunhofer.de/AAC/7.1auditionOutLeader_v2_rtb.mp4");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to use 8 different speakers.... Uhh, I'm 99% flash doesn't support that but it looks like 5.1 surround is supported. But [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html) is worth looking at.

### to split the stereo sound

To use the left and right speaker independently, do this:

Create 2 `SoundChannel` objects and 2 `Sound` objects. Set 1 to your desired left output and one to your right something like this

```
var leftSound:Sound = new Sound("leftSound");
var rightSound:Sound = new Sound("rightSound");
var trans:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(1, -1);//volume 1, panning full left
var leftChannel:SoundChannel = leftSound.play(0,1,trans);
trans.pan = 1; // set panning to full right
var rightChannel:SoundChannel = rightSound.play(0,1,trans);
```

Look it up in the documentation if this doesn't work.
[docs here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1f.html)

Do the same thing for additional channels but don't mess with the panning (or set them to 0) if you want the athmos to be evenly distributed.

### summary

1. Create a `Sound` object for each sound you want to play or song you want to play
2. Create a `SoundChannel` object for each channel you want to control.  You described a left, a right, and athmos(? Don't know what that is) so that is at least 3 channels.
3. Create a `SoundTransform` object
4. Play each channel using the desired transform settings as I illustrated above.

Comment: I din't understand. I need minimum 2 stereo outputs to play the sound on 4 speaker.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: See my summary above

Comment: If you don't understand how to do any of these steps (even though I've demonstrated it) post a new question. For instance, if you know how to do step 1 and 2, but step 3 has you stumped, post a new question asking how to do that step and be sure to show what you have tried and explain what isn't working about it. On stack overflow, you are expected to do the leg work yourself so if you haven't taken the time to even read the documentation I posted... please do.

Comment: See my edit at the top of my post. I think I misunderstood your goal. You are trying to use 8 *different* speakers with 8 *different* sounds? Like surround sound? I don't think you can.

Comment: Do you currently have at least some sound coming out of the 4 speakers? And you just need to split it left and right? Or are only two giving any output?

Comment: I think I have to play the sound in a more comfortable software then flash. I think its a shame for adobe not to support ASIO. Also it is not possible to select the audio device for an application.

Then I could make two apps, each playing on one sound card...

Answer (score 0):

what I have done to fix this: using Banana Voicemeeter to route the sound from two differnt apps to dfferent speakers.

Comment: Why two different apps? Are you not making just one full app in Flash? Also you should tag `AIR` in your question if you're making or involving some desktop application.